# Different way of using pointers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Given this:

```
int i[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int *p = i;
```

I know this:

```
p[0];
```

Is the same as this:

```
*(p + 0);
```

But... can somebody explain me why and what's the theoretical difference?

Thank you very much.

Comment: _'what's the theoretical difference?'_ There isn't any?!?

Comment: Arrays are contiguous, meaning they are located immediately in order in memory. Therefore you can just advance 4 bytes from the first index to reach the second, and each subsequent element. As long as you know the type of the object, you can index it in this fashion.

Comment: @Cyber: you don't even need to know the type... arithmetic on pointers works in multiples of the pointed-to object's size.

Comment: @hellfire: We don't go adding `c` tags to C++ code that might also be valid in C.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - it's educational. Frankly, if the title didn't include "C++", which language would you think it was written in?

Answer (score 3):

To the computer, there's no difference at all.  For `T*`.  For user-defined (smart pointer) types, one will use `operator+` and `operator*`, while the other uses `operator[]`.

To a programmer reading your code, subscripting suggests that you are accessing the nth element of an array of like items (all intervening items have the same type).  While pointer arithmetic suggests that you have a data structure with fixed offsets.

The lines get blurry when you're making a pointer though.  `&a[n]` and `a+n` are also equivalent, but I see the latter used with arrays far more than I see `*(a+n)` used with arrays.

In the end though, it's like variable naming, or any other case where there's more than one way to write the same thing (e.g. `while` vs `for` loops).  You can, by convention, assign additional meaning to the source code above and beyond the actual behavior.  But it won't be enforced, and different coding styles exist that use different conventions.

Comment: And to make it even more interesting a[n] is the same thing as n[a] ...

Comment: @dragosht: For builtin types only, yes.

Answer (score 3):

There is no semantic difference at all: `p[0]` is a syntactic sugar which is called `a subscripted designation of an element of an array object` or just a subscript operator shortly.
From the C++ Standard Working Draft 2012-01-16:
 `Except where it has been declared for a class (13.5.5), the subscript operator [] is interpreted in such a way that E1[E2] is identical to *((E1)+(E2)) by definition. Because of the conversion rules that apply to +, if E1 is an array and E2 an integer, then E1[E2] refers to the E2-th member of E1.`

One interesting part that was pointed in the comment to Ben Voigt answer:"a[n] is the same thing as n[a]" is also claimed in the standard:

```
Therefore, despite its asymmetric appearance, subscripting
is a commutative operation.
```

That's why we can do this (only for built in types: `Note: Except where it has been declared for a class`).

As for multidimensional array:

```
A consistent rule is followed for multidimensional arrays. If E 
is an n-dimensional array of rank i×j ×. . .×k, then E appearing
in an expression that is subject to the array-to-pointer conversion (4.2)
is converted to a pointer to an (n − 1)-dimensional array with rank
j × . . . × k. If the * operator, either explicitly or implicitly as 
a result of subscripting, is applied to this pointer, the result
is the pointed-to (n − 1)-dimensional array, which itself is 
immediately converted into a pointer.
```

For more information look C++11 standard `§ 8.3.4`.

This is the same sugar as `->` operator for accessing members of a struct or union, given a pointer to such: `p->a` == `(*p).a`. All this were added to language to make code more human readable and more elegant.

Comment: For this question, you should be quoting the C++ standard.  There are some subtle differences around the fringes of this rule.

Answer (score 2):

...there is no theoretical difference as far as I know. 
the p[0] operation does exactly what *(p + 0) does

Answer (score 0):

That's just [syntax sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for the same thing. Pointers are memory offsets from an initial element.